# Proof verification for the continuity of the identity mapping between the Euclidean Topology and Cofinite Topology.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity, proof-writing

I would like to verify my proof for the continuity of $f(x) = x$ from the Euclidean topology $(\mathbb{R},T)$ and cofinite topology $(\mathbb{R},S)$ and vice versa. I will be grateful if anything is pointed out. Thanks in advance.

Let :→ be continuous in every point of a set  such that ℙ(∈)=1.

If −→ then ()→().

But I have a counterexample for this theorem

Let  is a sequence of two dimension random variable =(1,2) such as 1=(0,1) and 2=−1. So we have
=(1,2)−→((0,1),(0,1))
Given :2→ and (,)=+.  is so a continuous function in 2. Arcording to the continuous mapping theorem, we must have
()=(1,2)→((0,1),(0,1))=(0,1)+(0,1)=(0,2‾√)
But
()=(1,2)=1+2=1−1=0
What is the error in my arguments?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure you can guarantee the existence of $N_y$ and $N_z$. You'd have to be using the fact that $(\mathbb{R}, T)$ is Hausdorff but given its topology I don't think it is.

Comment: I thought it is the case that ℝ in the standard topology is a Hausdorff space. Isn't that true?

Comment: Oh you're correct, I mixed up your directions in the proof.

Comment: There are quite a few conditions that are  equivalent to continuity and some are better suited for some Q's than others. One is that $ f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}V$ is closed in $X$ whenever $V$ is closed in $Y.$ In your Q, if $V$ is $S$-closed then $V$ is finite or $V=\Bbb R,$ so $f^{-1}V=V$  is $T$-closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prove that the identity map from $(\mathbb R,T)$ into $(\mathbb R,S)$ is continuous all you need is that $T$ is finer than $S$. And you proved that. There was no need to prove that it is strictly finer. But, since it is strictly finer, it follows immediately that the identity map from $(\mathbb R,S)$ into $(\mathbb R,T)$ is *not* continuous.

However, note that it is false that “If $U,V$ are nonempty open sets of any topological space $X$ […], then $U\cap V\neq\emptyset$”.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain why if it is strictly finer, then $x$ is not continuous from (ℝ,)  into (ℝ,)?

Comment: Also, what would be the correct justification for the contradiction?

Comment: Since $T$ is stricly finer that $S$, then $S$ is *not* finer than $T$ and so, as you know, the identity map from $(\mathbb R,S)$ into $(\mathbb R,T)$ is not continuous.